# get some specific line from a string

Tags: c#, string

In my C# application, I have a string that contains :

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929

for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

f:\Code\Code\Executable\test.cs(8,23): error CS0161: 'Class1.Test()': not all code paths return a value
f:\Code\Code\Executable\test.cs(14,20): error CS0161: 'Class1.GetNumber()': not all code paths return a value
```

From this string, I would like to get the following two lines and store them in two variables.

```
string error1 = f:\Code\Code\Executable\test.cs(8,23): error CS0161: 'Class1.Test()': not all code paths return a value

string error2 = f:\Code\Code\Executable\test.cs(14,20): error CS0161: 'Class1.GetNumber()': not all code paths return a value
```

How can I do this using C#?

Comment: You're reinventing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider, which does all of this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to keep each line which represents an error.

If your initial string is kept in the variable `text`, you could do:

```
List<string> keptLines = new List<string>();
foreach(string line in text.Split(new [] { '\r', '\n' })){
  if ( line.Contains("error CS0161:") ) //Or any other criterion
  {
    keptLines.Add(line);
  }
}
```

Comment: @YeasinAbedinSiam, splitting with `Environment.NewLine` is a much better way to write your code.

Comment: Yes, but I guess we don't know what "newLine" is used of our `text`: it may have been generated elsewhere, and use different line endings than the one our system is currently using. (e.g: he may want to run this C# code on Linux with Mono)

Answer (score 0):

If you know you just want the last two lines, this should work:

```
var lines = myString.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var error1 = lines[lines.Length - 2];
var error2 = lines[lines.Length - 1];
```

Or to get all lines after the 'header', you can do this:

```
var lines = myString.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var errors = new string[lines.Length - 3];
Array.Copy(lines, 3, errors, 0, errors.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var query = txt.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' })
             .Where(line => line.Contains("error"))
             .ToList();
```